# How to clear Datepicker value in Antd Form?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, antd

If trigger button inside same Form.Item with Datepicker it works, but if button is outside  datepicker does not clear.

I basicly try to clear Datepicker after submit.

It's strange, I could not understand it's antd bug or am I missing something else?

```
 <Form
    form={form}
    name="advanced_assessment_form"
    onFinish={() => setIsClear(!isClear);}
  >
    <Form.Item
      name="field"
      rules={[
        {
          required: true,
          message: "Input something!"
        }
      ]}
    >
      <DatePicker
        name="datepicker"
        onChange={(val) => {
          setResponseDate(val);
        }}
        value={isClear ? null : responseDate}
      />
      {/* This Button works! */}
      {/* <Button htmlType="submit" onClick={onButton}>
        {" "}
        Clear Datepicker{" "}
      </Button> */}
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item>
      {/* This Button does not work */}
      <Button htmlType="submit" onClick={onButton}>
        {" "}
        Clear Datepicker{" "}
      </Button>
    </Form.Item>
  </Form>
```

here sandbox code :
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-ardinghelli-53qtb?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution on antd Form API.

Just calling below function helps to clear all field.

```
form.resetFields();
```

if you want to set value to a specific field;

```
form.setFieldsValue({field: '01/01/2021/, 'DD/MM/YYYY')})
```

Cheer's